# Swift 3 range exception?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, nsrangeexception

```
let x = self.tableProduct.count
self.tableProduct = products
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
var insertedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
for i in x..<self.tableProduct.count {
    print("No : \(i)")
    insertedIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
}
print("Count = \(self.tableProduct.count)")
print(insertedIndexPaths)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertedIndexPaths, with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Here x is the current array count. Since I'm fetching in background after assigning I update array in second line. Then I start updating table view. Lets say initially my table has 50 records that is x, then I want to add row from 51 to self.tableProduct.count which is 100. In for loop I add index path my first index path is [0,51] and last index path looks like [0,99]. Then I start to insert my new rows, here it throws

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'`

error.When I add breakpoint to error it shows error in tableView.endUpdates() line.Here what I'm doing wrong? How can I solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the line `tableview.endUpdates()`

Comment: then It won't update the table Samarth Kejriwal

Comment: use `tableView.reloaddata()` instead of `tableview.endUpdates()`

Comment: then it will start from beginning.There is no use in adding rows.

Comment: Why do you want to add rows manually in the tableview? Whenever you fetch data dynamically then store it in your array and load the cell with your data.Simple

Comment: I'm having minimum of 20k records. If I did tableview.reloaddata() it will again reload all the data.

Comment: read my latest comment

Comment: I think you don't understand reload will reload all the records which means it reloads from 0 to 100 but add adds from 51 to 100 there is a huge difference in it.

Comment: If you're doing this in the background, it's likely that you have some kind of race condition. It looks like you're changing the range values while you're looping.

Comment: no it is in main thread. I create new instance of array before looping so the count won't change.